# RequestContextUtils.getLocale(request) vs LocaleContextHolder.getLocale() which one I should use in Spring MVC application?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is there have some principle of the selection between `RequestContextUtils.getLocale(request)` and `LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()`? Now, I don't know how to choose them, which one I should use in Spring MVC application?

Comment: Preferably neither, if you are in a controller just add a `Locale` parameter to your method signature and spring will inject it for you.

Comment: Not in a controller, but in some place.

Comment: Then use the `LocaleContextHolder` else you would have to pass around the `HttpRequest` to every method you can imagine...